# Why this code snippet produces `error: incompatible types: ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to <anonymous ArrayList<String>>`?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11, java-17

```
public class AnonymousAssign {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnonymousAssign().testAnonymousAssign();
    }

    public void testAnonymousAssign() {
        var list1 = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("");
        }};
        list1 = new ArrayList<String>(); // this line produces an error
        System.out.println(list1.getClass()); // print `class AnonymousAssign$1`

    }
}
```

```
 error: incompatible types: ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to <anonymous ArrayList<String>>
        list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Why is `var` assign make such type inference and not allow a seemingly straightforward and reasonable value reassignment ?**

---

### Some more infos

`System.out.println(list1.getClass());` would print `class AnonymousAssign$1`

but not a `class java.util.ArrayList`

---

Below is a tip from IntelliJ IDEA's 2022.3, it isn't meaningful.
[image: ide's tip does not seems useful]

---

Comment: Would you expect `var x = "hello"; x = new Object();` to work? That's basically equivalent, as far as the compiler is concerned: an initial assignment of a subclass, and then an attempt to later assign a superclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("");
    }};
```

creates an instance of an anonymous sub-class of `ArrayList<String>`. Therefore the inferred type of it is a sub-class of `ArrayList`, so you can't assign an instance of `ArrayList` to it later (unless that instance was also of the same sub-class of `ArrayList`, which is not possible, since it's an anonymous sub-class).

If you want the type of the variable to be `ArrayList`, you'll have to explicitly declare it so:

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("");
    }};
```

or even better:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("");
    }};
```

Now the second assignment will work.

Comment: The better solution is not to use the double-curly-brace thing at all; `var list1 = List.of(""); list = new ArrayList<>();` no problem…

Answer (score 1):

This error message is indicating that the variable "list1" is being assigned a new instance of an ArrayList of Strings, but it has been declared as a more specific type of ArrayList (an anonymous one) which is not compatible with the type of ArrayList being created. To fix this error, you can either change the declaration of "list1" to match the type of ArrayList being created, or you can change the type of ArrayList being created to match the declared type of "list1".